# Android Studio Java Activity loading several times on Android 12

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm not sure where to start with providing information for debugging on this issue, and will some guidance on what to upload for evaluation.

Let me start with a high level overview of the situation.
I'm working on a application for a project that is rather simple. It takes one of 16 values (1 to 16) that can be changed by UP and DOWN buttons and sends the values to a  micro-controller over Bluetooth. There is a loop that is monitoring the status of the sent value and its response. Then it updates a textview with the returned value. A good way to look as this is "Set Point/Actual"

This app was working on Android 8 and needed updating to work with the new permission requirements of Android 12. In the process of switching to the Android 12 tablet one of the activities reloads the layout 5 times before settling, but the other tablets are fine.

HELP .... Where do I start?

I have seen other post where people have uploaded active screen shots showing weird behavior. How can I capture this on a tablet to upload.

I can upload:
-- the Logcat file.
-- Code
-- etc...

EDIT to add video and Logcat file

The issue happens when "OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onCreate()" starts. I can not tell from the log file why onCreate() is re-starting 5 times.

Link to video on YouTube: [Link to video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/-X_O41MtSjE)

Logcat output ==============================================

```
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:ConfigureActivity: ALC-onPause()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:ConfigureActivity: Saving tractorId : 1234
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:ConfigureActivity: Saving hostId : 90
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:ConfigureActivity: Saving numberRows : 1
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: Start ContentView
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@f45d5a1[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowControllerCallback=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@f45d5a1[]
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=340 msg=resources_loaded
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: setWindowBackground: isPopOver=false color=ffffffff d=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@be58f87
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onCreate()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: initObjects()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onStart()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onResume()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: processCaptionVisibilityChanged: isStatusBarHidden=true
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: Data Loaded()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: updateInfo()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: check: return. pkg=com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree parent=null callers=com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setVisibility:4437 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity:5504 android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute:54 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:176 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@f45d5a1[]
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/InsetsSourceConsumer: setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=21, host=com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree.OperatePlanterActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:266 android.view.InsetsController.collectSourceControls:1281 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1142 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1536 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1517 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1071 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1046 android.view.ViewRootImpl.controlInsetsForCompatibility:3171 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:1609 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:529 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/InsetsSourceConsumer: setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=20, host=com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree.OperatePlanterActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:266 android.view.InsetsController.collectSourceControls:1281 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1142 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1536 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1517 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1071 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1046 android.view.ViewRootImpl.controlInsetsForCompatibility:3171 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:1609 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:529 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/InsetsSourceConsumer: setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=1, host=com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree.OperatePlanterActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:266 android.view.InsetsController.collectSourceControls:1281 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1142 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1536 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1517 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1071 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1046 android.view.ViewRootImpl.controlInsetsForCompatibility:3171 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:1609 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:529 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/InsetsSourceConsumer: setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=0, host=com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree.OperatePlanterActivity, from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:266 android.view.InsetsController.collectSourceControls:1281 android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1142 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1536 android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1517 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1071 android.view.InsetsController.hide:1046 android.view.ViewRootImpl.controlInsetsForCompatibility:3171 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:1609 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:529 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@f45d5a1 TM=true
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: check: windowingMode=1 isFullSize=true isPopOver=false allowedPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=true this: DecorView@f45d5a1[OperatePlanterActivity]
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@f45d5a1[OperatePlanterActivity]
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,2560,1600) new=(0,0,2560,1600) req=(2560,1600)0 dur=11 res=0x7 s={true 0xb4000075cdd31090} ch=true fn=-1
27814-27848/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: mThreadedRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 0xb4000075cdd31090} hwInitialized=true
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:11612 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4248 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2948 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: Creating frameDrawingCallback nextDrawUseBlastSync=false reportNextDraw=true hasBlurUpdates=false
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: Creating frameCompleteCallback
27814-27857/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: Received frameDrawingCallback frameNum=1. Creating transactionCompleteCallback=false
27814-27848/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/BufferQueueProducer: [ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]#4(BLAST Consumer)4](id:6ca600000004,api:1,p:27814,c:27814) queueBuffer: queued for the first time.
27814-27848/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/BLASTBufferQueue: [ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]#4](f:0,a:0) onFrameAvailable the first frame is available
27814-27848/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/OpenGLRenderer: DrawFrameTask::run() invoke frameCompleteCallback
27814-27848/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: Received frameCompleteCallback  lastAcquiredFrameNum=1 lastAttemptedDrawFrameNum=1
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: [DP] pdf(0)  mWindowCallbacks.size= 1  fn= mFrameNumberandroid.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$addFrameCompleteCallbackIfNeeded$3$ViewRootImpl:5102 android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: [DP] rdf (fn= -1) 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/ViewRootImpl@d304bb2[OperatePlanterActivity]: reportDrawFinished (fn= -1) 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/ViewRootImpl@88ef5fb[ConfigureActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onPause()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: Saved Data()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: Start ContentView
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@7b81b7d[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowControllerCallback=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@7b81b7d[]
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=340 msg=resources_loaded
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: setWindowBackground: isPopOver=false color=ffffffff d=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@e028ec3
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onCreate()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: initObjects()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onStart()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: ALC-onResume()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: processCaptionVisibilityChanged: isStatusBarHidden=true
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: Data Loaded()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree D/MSG:OperatePlanterActivity: updateInfo()
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: check: return. pkg=com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree parent=null callers=com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setVisibility:4437 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity:5504 android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute:54 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:176 
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@7b81b7d[]
27814-27814/com.graham.grahamrowclearerthree I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
```

Comment: What does "reloads the layout 5 times before settling" mean? Reload how? Settling how? What is the actual problem you are observing (is it visual, does it crash). Have you looked the Logcat output for clues?

Comment: Can you share some code from the activity in question? Probably the `onCreate` method and anything else that gets called in the beginning from `onCreate`. It would also be helpful to see what code is executed when you press the start button.